# Как вставить php код внутрь выводимого html через php?

Tags: php, html

Код выводится вот так

```
echo <<<html

<input class="margin"  id='****' type="text" name="name"
value="php echo @$data['email'];><p>

html;
```

Надо как то вывести автоматический ввод инфы в поле, но обычные 'тут бесполезны'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вставки в `heredoc` значений массива, нужно использовать `{}` и оборачивать переменную `{$array['key']}` - то есть так:

```
echo <<<html

<input class="margin"  id='****' type="text" name="name"
value="{$data['email']}">

html;
```

В остальных случаях, использовать обычную вставку:

```
$a = 1111;
$arr = [1,2,3];
echo <<<html
$a
{$arr[1]}
html; // 1111 2
```

Это все написано в [документации по строкам](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)